# Get Response from Socket in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to integrate Socket in my app for real-time chat. Backend is done on node.js and frontend is developed on React and both are working fine.

I am having issue adding socket in my Swift Project.

In my `aaHandlers()` function below, I expect to get a JSON response with detail of 4 users. Its working fine in Web app but not in Swift. Am I doing it right?

Here is the code

```
import Foundation
import SocketIO


let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://chatsapi.dummyUrl.io")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
 let socket = manager.defaultSocket
 let socketConnectionStatus = socket.status

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }

    func addHandlers() {
        socket.on("get_all_user_list") { (data, ack) in
            print("KK get_all_user_list", data,ack) // this line never gets called. I tried putting breakpoints.
        }
    }


    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }


    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }

}
```

P.S: Socket is connected.

Here is what I get in console:

```
> 2020-04-13 18:14:05.790193+0530 SocketTry[41289:9400138] LOG
> SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: get_all_user_list
```

Comment: You could install a minimal node program locally on your machine and test it from there (`npm install --save socket.io`), e.g. by calling something like `socket.emit('get_all_user_list', '<some json>');`. Then change your URL in the Swift program to `http://localhost:3000`. Does it work then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if you using any authentication in the socket or not. If you are using authentication you need to set the configuration in your swift code. 
Here AUTHTOKEN which is user token you received from your login response from your server. AUTH_USER_ID which you received from your login response from your server.

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {

        let socketUrl = "https://chatsapi.dummyUrl.io"

        let specs: SocketIOClientConfiguration = [
            .log(true),
            .connectParams(getConnectionParam())]
        socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: socketUrl)!, config: specs)
        socket = socketManager?.defaultSocket
    }

    func getConnectionParam() -> [String: Any] {
            return ["auth": "AUTHTOKEN", "user_id": "AUTH_USER_ID", "timeZone": "\(Date().localTimeZoneName)"]
    }

    func addHandlers() {
        socket.on("get_all_user_list") { (data, ack) in
            print("KK get_all_user_list", data,ack) // this line never gets called. I tried putting breakpoints.
        }
    }


    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }


    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have established a connection to the server whenever the app becomes active.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
}
```

And one more thing An important notice: The above socket.on(...) method will be invoked automatically by **the Socket.IO every time that the server sends the user list**.